# Custom Spring Boot starter: how do you contribute i18n messages to the MessageSource?

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, spring-boot

I'm writing a custom Spring Boot starter that other developers will drop into their applications, and this starter contains out-of-the-box controllers and UI screens.

These UI screens are internationalized and the i18n keys/values are in a package file: `com/foo/wherever/i18n.properties`.

I want to ensure that when my starter is loaded at startup, that these i18n.properties are available in the application's `MessageSource` automatically so that my UI pages work (rendered via normal Spring Controller + ViewResolver + View implementations) *without the app developer having to specify this file themselves*.

In other words, they should be able to add my starter to their runtime classpath and everything 'just works' without the need to configure anything.

Now, I have discovered that the app developer can create their own `src/main/resources/messages.properties` file *and* manually configure the additional messages file in `application.properties`:

```
spring.messages.basename = messages, com.foo.wherever.i18n
```

And this will work.

However, this requires both of the following:

1. They must manually configure the `spring.messages.basename` property - it's not automatic. and
2. They must have their own `messages.properties` file in their application classpath.  If a `messages.properties` file does not exist, `spring.messages.basename` doesn't even work.  Even if they don't care about i18n, this is still required - not desirable.

I suppose I *could* move my i18n.properties file to a classpath:/messages.properties file in the starter .jar, but that doesn't seem like a good solution:  if the app dev has their own messages.properties file only one of them would be read, resulting in missing message values.

It seems as if Spring Boot [MessageSourceAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.java) should have a concept of a `CompositeMessageSource` that iterates over one or more `MessageSource` instances that are available (and `Order`ed) in the Spring ApplicationContext and *that* is used by the DispatcherServlet.  This would allow any starter to contribute to the available messages just by declaring a `MessageSource` in their auto config

Is it possible to do what I ask? What is the most 'hands off' solution for the app developer?

Comment: Just wondering if what you mean by 'com/foo/wherever/i18n.properties' is that the messages property file should reside in the same directory as the JSP view (or same package as the view, if using something else than JSPs)? This is the way message resources are handeled in struts2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is long shot but you can try to use [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html).

Idea is following:

1. Take "messageSource" bean out of the application context. Note that it might but does not have to be a spring boot's one if e.g. developer wants to use its own implementation and don't use spring boot autoconfiguration.
2. Replace it with your own implementation that tries to resolve "your keys" and the rest delegate to original message source. Or vice versa if you want to make possible to override your translations by developer (there can be problems if original message source does not throw exception for unknown keys).

But there might be a better way to do that.

Comment: Just revisiting this - Spring doesn't have support for this currently, so this is still the best answer I've been able to find.  Answer awarded!

Answer (score 17):

I set this up in the following way.  I'm only currently supporting en_US but it is setup to handle any number of languages using internationalization(i18n).

### View the Code here

View the code gist here: [Code on github gist](https://gist.github.com/anataliocs/715cb36c3604a467d38d)

### Add Message Source and Default locale Beans

Add these beans to your Application.java to set your default locale and configure the location of your message props

[image: Message source and default locale]

---

### Create Message Service

Service will get the default locale from the session and then get the message text from your props

[image: Setup Message svc]

---

### Use the Message service in Controller

Inject the message svc and then pass in the id to get the value from the props file

[image: Use svc in controller]

---

### Add message.properties file in the locale

Goto /resources:

- create the locale folder
- create a file called messages_en_US.properties

[image: message props]

---

### Read more

You can view a more complete article on this subject here:
[Spring Boot Internationalization i18n using Message Properties](http://codedevstuff.blogspot.com/2015/05/spring-boot-internationalization-with.html)

---

### Look at the Code

View the code gist here:
[Code on github gist](https://gist.github.com/anataliocs/715cb36c3604a467d38d)

Comment: It's nice to post answer, but code should be copiable. It's possible to copy it from posted link.

Comment: @xdg the Gist is version controlled so if I update the Gist, the code copied onto Stack Overflow will be outdated.  I do update my Gists on a regular basis.

Comment: Updated answer so link to code is at the top of answer and more prominant

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question - the question is about how to get internationalization working in a spring boot starter *without* forcing the user to define these concepts in their local application.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old and answered question by now, but I encountered the same problem the other day, and wrote a blog post about how I've decided to solve it. I thought I should share it here since I got some inspiration for my solution from this thread.

In short, it takes sodik's idea of intercepting the creation of the `MessageSource` bean, but instead of using a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` I'm using a `BeanPostProcessor`, and rather than replacing the original `MessageSource` in the application context, I just add my own as its parent:

```
@Bean
BeanPostProcessor messageSourceCustomExtender() {
    return new BeanPostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof HierarchicalMessageSource && beanName.equals("messageSource")) {
                ResourceBundleMessageSource parent = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
                parent.setBasename("custom");

                ((HierarchicalMessageSource) bean).setParentMessageSource(parent);
            }

            return bean;
        }
    };
}
```

You can read the full blog post where I explain some caveats about my solution: http://www.thomaskasene.com/2016/08/20/custom-spring-boot-starter-messagesource/

### Update

After some tinkering I realized that using a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` was wrong as it will cause the original `MessageSource` bean to be created prematurely and ignore application properties (most importantly, `spring.messages.basename`). That means the application won't be able to configure these properties. See the excerpt from the [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) documentation below.

> A BeanFactoryPostProcessor may interact with and modify bean definitions, but never bean instances. Doing so may cause premature bean instantiation, violating the container and causing unintended side-effects. If bean instance interaction is required, consider implementing BeanPostProcessor instead.

I've updated the example above to use `BeanPostProcessor` instead, which alters the bean instance rather than the bean definition.