# Thymeleaf and Spring Boot not reading properties from localization files - Question marks appear instead of the localized string

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, localization, thymeleaf

When attempting to localize a static string the message is displayed surrounded with questionmarks "??"

e.g. **??ticket.type_en_US??**

```
<p th:text="#{ticket.type}">Blah</p>
```

- I am using SpringBoot 1.3.6.RELEASE
- Thymeleaf: 3.0.0.RELEASE
- thymeleaf-spring4 artifact

I have configured the basename of my messages in application.properties

and the contents of that messages.properties and messages_en_US.properties is:

```
ticket.type=BUGS!!!!
```

**Config:**

```
spring.messages.basename=messages
```

**Output on startup:**

> 2016-07-19 08:38:28.673 DEBUG 5175 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Using MessageSource
>   [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource:
>   basenames=[messages]]

I also tried programatically using the MessageResource in the code below. I placed the messages.properties file in the same folder as the application.properties file. src/main/resources/

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("controller") 
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        engine.setMessageSource(messageSource);
        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**For completeness here is my application config (like others I had to exluse the Thymeleaf class):**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

I have also verified that the message bundles are being loaded by pring out the contents on one of my REST end-point calls:

```
@Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<MyData> getData() {
        System.out.println("HERE 1 in Conversions");

        System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage("ticket.type", null, Locale.US));

        return getTheData();
    }
```

This prints out the following so I know spring-boot is loading the resource bundles, but Thymeleaf is not picking them up somehow:

```
BUGS!!!!
```

Here is my full HTML page, perhaps there is an issue with it:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>

    <title>Kitchen Sink</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
          rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />

    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"
            th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js}"></script>

    <link href="../static/css/mike.css"
          th:href="@{css/mike.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">

        <h1>Hello</h1>

        <h2>Welcome to the Kitchen Sink!</h2>

        <p th:text="#{ticket.type}">Blah</p>

        <p th:text="#{test.type}">dssfgf</p>

      </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750292/custom-spring-boot-starter-how-do-you-contribute-i18n-messages-to-the-messageso

Comment: Have you tried `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` instead of `ResourceBundleMessageSource` ?

Comment: Why are you configuring it yourself? Spring Boot already configures thyme leaf, localization etc. for you... Work with the framework instead of around the framework.

Comment: @Saravana I tried to modify my code as well and use "classpath:messages" and it dies not work

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, that is what I would like to do. I started out this way, but then after looking at example I tried to configure it programatically. I removed those 4 functions and it is matched on startup. MessageSourceAutoConfiguration matched
      - Bundle found for spring.messages.basename: messages (MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.ResourceBundleCondition)
      - @ ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.MessageSource; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

Comment: So it looks like MessageSourceAutoConfiguration is initialized with messages, but still no luck in Thymeleaf picking up the file

Comment: I've updated the question and removed the programatic configuration of the resource bundles. I have also Autowired the bundles in a REST end point and printed out the contents of the property and it works. So I'm struggling with why Thymeleaf is not picking them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, so I figured it out. Thanks @M.Deinum for poitning out that I should just let spring-boot and Thymeleaf do what they are supposed to do.

I had to set the:

```
engine.setMessageSource(messageSource);
```

and also add the:

```
@Bean
```

to the 2 other functions. This allowed the MessageSource to be passed into the engine and resolve the properties correctly.

I will update the question above with the correct source so people can use it for referene

Answer (score 1):

Please add

> @EnableAutoConfiguration

in your Spring boot startup its look like

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and code from your post didn't work for me. The source of my issue was, that I didn't have message.proprerties (without any language).

I had:

```
messages_en.properties
messages_de.properties
messages_es.properties
```

but it didn't work.

It started working only when I added

```
messages.properties
```